# How to fix this saddle for my road bike?

Tags: road-bike, saddle

I have this bike:
https://www.boc24.de/p/compel-rr-100/213327/#itemId=213327-1

I disassembled my bike and have Problems putting my saddle back together.

[image]

[image]

**What i tried:**

Putting from both sides:

[image]

What i expected:

Having only one screw. (Maybe i also confuse having two,..)

(different bike)

[image]

Comment: The round steel inserts that the bolts go through look correctly placed in the seatpost clamp. Clearly, neither of the allen bolts you have is long enough to go all the way through the clamp. Are you sure you have the correct bolts? It looks like you should only have one long bolt like your gif seems to show (but please note, it's very unclear and it's going to cause motion sickness in some people)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a mixup somewhere.  Those bolts look wrong - given there's a clearance hole in one cylinder and a threaded hole in the other, one bolt should pass through the first and thread into the second.

```
    +-+   +-+
[]===========>
    +-+   +-+
   slip   threaded
```

As yours is pictured, the two bolts would push the ends of the clamp apart, if they could both get a grip.

Look around for the missing bolt.   Those two look like water bottle cage bolts, or possibly stem bolts.  What else did you take apart that may have become mixed ?